# flocker-docker-plugin doesn't work

Tags: ssl, docker, twisted, twisted.web

I have 2 centos 7.1 nodes and I'm trying to get flocker running on it. I've followed the installation steps exactly however when it comes to running the following command to test to see if flocker-docker-plugin works:

`docker run -v apples:/data --volume-driver flocker busybox sh -c "echo hello > /data/file.txt"`

I get the error:

`Error response from daemon: Error looking up volume plugin flocker: Plugin not found`

The flocker-docker-plugin logs show the following:

```
{"request_body": null, "url": "https://foo.bar.com:4523/v1/state/nodes/by_era/b72bb203-b174-4241-a03a-6171cbc10f30", "timestamp": 1451201332.659948, "action_status": "started", "task_uuid": "1ae63069-286c-44fa-9dd2-6751ca0efe63", "action_type": "flocker:apiclient:http_request", "method": "GET", "task_level": [1]}
{"task_uuid": "1ae63069-286c-44fa-9dd2-6751ca0efe63", "error": false, "timestamp": 1451201332.749499, "message": "Starting factory <twisted.web.client._HTTP11ClientFactory instance at 0x2fc7710>", "message_type": "twisted:log", "task_level": [3]}
{"exception": "twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived", "task_level": [4], "action_type": "flocker:apiclient:http_request", "reason": "[<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>>]", "timestamp": 1451201333.050012, "task_uuid": "1ae63069-286c-44fa-9dd2-6751ca0efe63", "action_status": "failed"}
{"task_uuid": "c8d28668-f21b-4863-bf20-6c30f54c3d25", "error": true, "timestamp": 1451201333.05045, "message": "Unhandled Error\nTraceback (most recent call last):\nFailure: twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>>]\n", "message_type": "twisted:log", "task_level": [1]}
{"task_uuid": "36f1ddd5-c5fa-4438-85d7-131e7752f8d3", "error": true, "timestamp": 1451201333.050727, "message": "main function encountered error\nTraceback (most recent call last):\nFailure: twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>>]\n", "message_type": "twisted:log", "task_level": [1]}
{"task_uuid": "08bd8f13-0a8e-43f4-8b80-b4cf5b317f00", "error": false, "timestamp": 1451201333.051034, "message": "Stopping factory <twisted.web.client._HTTP11ClientFactory instance at 0x2fc7710>", "message_type": "twisted:log", "task_level": [1]}
{"task_uuid": "8f0fd1ef-19ca-4033-b16f-6d42e33eda1a", "error": false, "timestamp": 1451201333.052711, "message": "Main loop terminated.", "message_type": "twisted:log", "task_level": [1]}
flocker-docker-plugin.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Unit flocker-docker-plugin.service entered failed state.
flocker-docker-plugin.service failed.
flocker-docker-plugin.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Started Flocker Docker Plugin.
Starting Flocker Docker Plugin...
```

Also running `uft-flocker-volumes --control-service=foo.bar.net list-nodes` returns:

```
jonathan@ubuntu:~/Flocker/sc-test-cluster$ uft-flocker-volumes --control-service=foo.bar.com list-nodes
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived
[<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>>]
```

Update:

I tried downgrading to docker 1.8.2 and tried rerunning the command, didn't work, same error.

Output of ls /etc/flocker:

```
[root@sc-test2 jonathan]# ls /etc/flocker
agent.yml  cluster.crt  node.crt  node.key  plugin.crt  plugin.key

[root@sc-test1 jonathan]# ls /etc/flocker
agent.yml    control-service.crt  node.crt  plugin.crt
cluster.crt  control-service.key  node.key  plugin.key
```

Update:1/1/2016
I set the following environment variables as per the kubernetes docs http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/examples/flocker/.

```
export FLOCKER_CONTROL_SERVICE_HOST=foo.bar.com
export FLOCKER_CONTROL_SERVICE_CA_FILE=/etc/flocker/cluster.crt
export FLOCKER_CONTROL_SERVICE_CLIENT_CERT_FILE=/etc/flocker/node.crt
export FLOCKER_CONTROL_SERVICE_CLIENT_KEY_FILE=/etc/flocker/node.key
export FLOCKER_CONTROL_SERVICE_PORT=4523
```

And I got a different error when running the command

`jonathan@ubuntu:~/Flocker/sc-test-cluster$ uft-flocker-volumes --control-service=sc-test1.cloudapp.net list-nodes`

```
wget: error getting response: Connection reset by peer
===========================================================================
Unable to establish network connectivity from inside a container.

If you see an error message above, that may give you a clue how to fix it.

If you run docker in a VM, restarting the VM often helps, especially if
you have changed network (and/or DNS servers) since starting the VM.

If you are using docker-machine (e.g. as part of docker toolbox), you can
run the following command (or similar) to do that:

    docker-machine restart default && eval $(docker-machine env default)

To ignore this check, and proceed anyway (e.g. if you know you are offline)
set IGNORE_NETWORK_CHECK=1
===========================================================================
```

So I set the flag to see what happens:
`jonathan@ubuntu:~/Flocker/sc-test-cluster$ export IGNORE_NETWORK_CHECK=1`

And bam! The same error :(

```
jonathan@ubuntu:~/Flocker/sc-test-cluster$ uft-flocker-volumes --control-service=sc-test1.cloudapp.net list-nodes
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>>]
```

Is the wget error a helpful clue as to what may be happening?

Comment: I would suggest you to go into source code (since ```Python``` has an obvious syntax) and try to find out what exactly raises the OpenSSL exception.

Comment: That's beginning to seem inevitable. I noted though that the request is made to https://foo.bar.com:4523 I.e. the control service. This is just a guess but what if I setup an ssl certificate on the control service , which is not currently setup. Might that be the issue?

Comment: I know that ```requests``` library often gets stuck with the system-level SSL certificates and it use ```OpenSSL``` as a backend. Probably you need to check if all of the system certs are "visible" from Python's ```OpenSSL```

Comment: I have to ask, how exactly would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

> > Error response from daemon: Error looking up volume plugin flocker: Plugin not found

This might be due to the control-service hostname on the agent.yml is not configured correctly. Make sure it's the host of the control-server node, not the agent node itself.